# What is the difference between a target group and security group in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm trying to get up and running with ECS and Load Balancing in AWS and I'm trying to understand the roles of the various components involved: load balancer, security group, target group.

From what I understand, security groups act as firewalls to open ports from the load balancer to specific EC2 instances. However what I don't understand is what's the purpose of a target group. If the security group routes traffic from the load balancer to the EC2 instance, what is the target group doing?

Comment: Purpose: Load balancing to multiple HTTP applications across machines.             
target group is used to route requests to one or more registered targets. for example create one target group for user requests, when http request method has /user it will route to user target group.

Comment: Isn't the security group routing requests to the registered targets?